# why's use edit_password_reset_url instead of edit_password_reset_path in password reset template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I saw this code in ROR application from railstutorial.org.

`File: view/user_mailer/password_reset.html.erb`

```
<h1><%= t ".heading" %></h1>
<p><%= t ".message"%></p>
<%= link_to t(".rs_password"), edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token,
  email: @user.email) %>
<p><%= t ".timelink"%></p>
<p><%= t ".warning"%></p>
```

So, why use edit_password_reset_url. i use _path then rails have `undefined method edit_password_reset_path`. So, Have another way to use _path ?

- I think a reason that, use _url return : `http://localhost:3000/password_resets/{token}/edit?email=email08%40gmail.com`
- _path only retrurn: `/password_resets/{token}/edit`

Answer (score 0):

it is because _path gives the relative path, and _url gives absolute path.

In an email,  receiver needs an absolute path to your application

> _path helpers provide a site-root-relative path. You should probably use this most of the time.
>
> _url helpers provide an absolute path, including protocol and server name. I've found that I mainly use these in emails when creating links
>   to the app on the server. They should mainly be used when providing
>   links for external use. (Think email links, RSS, and things like the
>   copy and paste URL field under a YouTube video's "Share" section.)

Comment: but why i try edit to edit_password_reset_path(@user.reset_token), application raise error `undefined method edit_password_reset_path`. Does it have sent email with relative path?

Comment: can you please share output of 

rake routes | grep edit_password_reset

Comment: Absolutely, Return `edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)     password_resets#edit`

Comment: I'm add `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.edit_password_reset_path` then ok, Do you know why with `_url` don't need `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`  and `_path` need that ?